# How to get records from the table which is not available in other table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables namely
roominfo and guestrecordtransac...roominfo containd room_id,room_no and roomtype fields 
whereas guestrecordtransac contains id,roomtype,roomno ,checkindate ,checkoutdate fields

I tried like this

```
    select room_no FROM roominfo WHERE room_no NOT IN (select roomno from guestrocordtransac where roomtype='".$roomtype."' between '".$check_in."'  and '".$check_out."'
) and roomtype='".$roomtype."'
```

**I want the room_no from roominfo of particular type and  which is not between the date of checkin andd checkout**

Answer (score 0):

(your question is not clear, try to give information more clearly)

I think this something like what you require/asking for :

```
select room_no FROM roominfo WHERE room_no NOT IN (select roomno from
guestrocordtransac where roomtype='".$roomtype."' 
AND CURDATE() between '".$check_in."'  and '".$check_out."`'
```